# Test.startTest and Test.stopTest affecting RestContext

Tags: apex, failing-tests, restresource

I have a very weird issue related to an Apex RestResource that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

I have an Apex class defined as a RestResource and am trying to test the functionality. In one particular sandbox (passes in 3 others), simply wrapping the call in Test.startTest/Test.stopTest causes the RestContext.response property to be set to null.

Here's what I have in a nutshell:

```
@HttpPost
public static void routeAndProcessRequest(){
    try{
        RestContext.response.responseBody = response; // processing code omitted for simplicity
        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        RestContext.response.statusCode = 200;
    }catch(Exception e){

        // handle errors
        
    }
}
```

Here is my test method:

```
RestContext.request = new RestRequest();
RestContext.response = new RestResponse();
RestContext.request.requestURI = 'some/url/here';
RestContext.request.httpMethod = 'POST';

Test.startTest();
    ApexRestResource.routeAndProcessRequest();
Test.stopTest();

System.assertEquals(200, RestContext.response.statusCode, 'Should be a 200 response code');
System.assertNotEquals(null, RestContext.response.responseBody, 'Response should not be null');
```

Simply the presence of Test.start/stopTest causes `System.assertEquals(200, RestContext.response.statusCode, 'Should be a 200 response code');` to throw an `Attempt to de-reference a null object` exception. If Test.start/stopTest is removed or commented out from the method, everything passes with flying colors.

Examining the debug logs, everything appears to operate exactly as expected until the asserts are reached. I even see the line executing where addHeader is called so the response is not null there.

I should note I have a number of test methods for different features of the same RestResource that do not have this issue (and as mentioned, the method in question executes without a hitch in all other environments it's been run in).

What could be happening here?

Edit: Adding some additional context in hopes it may help. The logic I'm trying to test creates an object that has a lot of automation on it. Not sure if this matters. Additionally, I've noticed something in the debug logs that seems off.

```
17:38:23.746 (40757223556)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[3]|System.RestContext.request|System.RestRequest|true|true
17:38:23.746 (40757233184)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[4]|System.RestContext.response|System.RestResponse|true|true
17:38:23.746 (40757266024)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[776]|Bytes:112
17:38:23.746 (40757274184)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[776]|Bytes:5
17:38:23.746 (40757305313)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|RestContext.RestContext()
17:38:23.746 (40757310157)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
17:38:23.746 (40757324175)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1]|RestContext
17:38:23.746 (40757463408)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[778]
17:38:23.746 (40757501199)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[778]|Bytes:38
17:38:23.746 (40757547957)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[780]
17:38:23.746 (40757571113)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[780]|Bytes:156
17:38:23.746 (40757577791)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[780]|Bytes:10
17:38:23.746 (40757588229)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|RestResponse.RestResponse()
17:38:23.746 (40757592730)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
17:38:23.746 (40757599599)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1]|RestResponse
```

When Test.start/stopTest are omitted, this block shows up in the debug log once when the request/response is instantiated before startTest. With Test.start/stopTest present, this same block also appears in the log after Test.stopTest executes. It seems to 'reset' the values (?) so anything done by the RestResource apex class is lost.

Comment: Has this sandbox gone Winter '24 and the others haven't?

Comment: @NickCook Unfortunately not, all of the environments involved are on Summer '23 (patch 18.5).